# Saving excel sheets as separate documents in pdf

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, vba, print-to-pdf

At work we export invoice data into an excel document where each invoice is put into a separate excel sheet.

At the moment we use BullZip pdf to print, but ideally I'd like to click print and the documents would save to pdf with the title of the sheet as its name. Is this possible?

Nb. We use BullZip as it adds on our letterhead to the document

Answer (score 0):

You can save individual worksheets as pdf from office 2010 onwards including excel 2010. [See here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Save-as-PDF-d85416c5-7d77-4fd6-a216-6f4bf7c7c110)

As for the idea of putting letterheads on invoices you can do this with page setups formatting the header and footer information.